# why we add class name when we are declaring and implementing a method in java?

Tags: java

I was going through a java code written in spring mvc web application. 
why we add class name when we are declaring and implementing a method in java?
What is the purpose of adding class name in such a way ?
is this anything related to aggregation(dependency of that particular class) !!

```
public ClassName someMethod(int xyz){
....
}
```

Comment: Not everything is a procedure. There might be functions, also. :)

Comment: This is the data type what will be returned by this function/methode. My hint: Please start learning programming from the very basics.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov Java doesn't have functions, it has methods

Comment: [Read this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: I know, @Stultuske. :)

Comment: @bub Presumably this user is coming from a language like Python where return types don't need to be explicitly declared...?

Comment: @DJX possible, but if so, when first stepping into Java, reading up the first chapters of a book to be able to understand the syntax should be done before trying to understand an application by reading Spring MVC code.

Comment: thank you Konstantin Yovkov :)

Comment: thank you Stultuske :)  what will happen when the return type is class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the method's return type. If you had read even a single tutorial it should be clear to you.

Comment: I know its a return type .why className instead of int void etc

Comment: Because the method is returning an instance of `ClassName`, not an `int` or nothing (`void`). You can't lie about what the method is returning, that would be counterproductive.

Answer (score 3):

We add a (complex) type only if the declared method returns a value of this type.
It is not necessary for the method to return a value, methods can be `void` or return a value of a [primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Learn more about defining a method in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)